# MVC Area Routing Post Loging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an area named aves. After a user has been successfully authenticated, if their subscription type area is for aves, I'm needing to redirect to /aves. That part seems to work. What isn't working correctly is the URL of the route. I'm needing it to just be /aves or /Aves. The image below is what's being returned.

[image: Example of returned URL]

My Code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<LoginAuthResult> Authenticate(LoginViewModel details)
    {
        var authResult = _as.AuthenticateUser(details);
        if (authResult.success)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Index","Birds", new { area = authResult.SubscriptionArea});
        }
        return authResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RedirectToAction

```
return RedirectToAction("action", "controller", new { area = "area" });
```